# Play QuickTime Video in WPF

Tags: wpf, video, quicktime

Is it possible to play a QuickTime Video in WPF? If yes, can anyone provide me the resources.

Answer (score 1):

Quicktime is a tricky thing on Windows.  The APIs pretty much don't exist for any language except C++.  Here's some documentation from the Apple developer website; [Quicktime Development For Windows](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/QuickTime/RM/QTforWindows/QTforWindows/C-Chapter/chapter_1000_section_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000940-BuildingQuickTimeCapabilityIntoaWindowsApplication-SW1).  But I doubt this will be useful for your WPF development.

Another option is to use the [Quicktime ActiveX control/COM object](http://developer.apple.com/quicktime/activexcontrol.html).  Its essentially a built in player with minimal control.